# How the react router can handle request url like: localhost:9000/blah/#token=albasdf

Tags: reactjs, react-router

We have a requirement that needs to handle some URL like following:

```
localhost:9000/blah/#token=albasdf
```

It's weird to use `#token=abcd` not `?token=abcd`, but it's requirement.

Any idea how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.hash` like this:

```js
// window.location.hash = #token=abcd
var match = window.location.hash.match(/\#(.+)=(.+)/)
if (match){
   var key = match[1]; // token
   var value = match[2]; // abcd

}
```

Comment: Shall I put this piece of code in a component or routes file? Could you please put some context around? thanks.